# Graylog - fluentbit -WARN - GELF message is missing mandatory "host" field

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, opensearch, fluent-bit, graylog

I used graylog helm chart that has mongodb and opensearch integration from [here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/kong-z/graylog)

After setting up graylog in EKS, I get same repeated warning in Graylog logs like this:

```
2023-06-21T22:40:01.215558613Z stdout F 2023-06-21 22:40:01,215 WARN    [GelfCodec] - GELF message <8ec644f1-1084-11ee-88ee-ea5420893a8a> (received from <10.10.1.38:39263>) is missing mandatory "host" field. - {}
```

Here is my configuration:

```
    [INPUT]
        Name               tail
        Tag                kube.*
        Path               /var/log/containers/*.log
        Parser             docker
        DB                 /var/log/flb_graylog.db
        DB.Sync            Normal
        Docker_Mode        On
        Buffer_Chunk_Size  512KB
        Buffer_Max_Size    5M
        Rotate_Wait        30
        Mem_Buf_Limit      30MB
        Skip_Long_Lines    On
        Refresh_Interval   10

    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Merge_Log On
        Merge_Log_Key log
        Keep_Log Off
        K8S-Logging.Parser On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
        Annotations Off
        Labels On

    [OUTPUT]
        Name                    gelf
        Match                   *
        Host                    graylog
        Port                    12201
        Mode                    udp
        Gelf_Short_Message_Key  log
```

Ideal outcome should be not to overfill Graylog journal logs with this message. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What's your Fluent Bit version?
Is your parser correct?
Try with a stdout output to see the message.